# How to use retryAssertionTimeout in nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js

In the Nightwatch API Reference (http://nightwatchjs.org/api#assertions) they show that you can use retry for Assertions, but not how to define it. The path to my global variables is set in the nightwatch.json:

```
 "globals_path" : "data/ftm_data.js",
```

in ftm_data.js i defined:

```
retryAssertionTimeout = 2000
module.exports = {
url:'https://10.99.8.81',
usersToCreate:[
  {.....
```

and so on. but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

> retryAssertionTimeout = 2000

should be in the

> module.exports = {

`module.exports = {
    retryAssertionTimeout: 2000,
    url:'https://10.99.8.81',
    usersToCreate:[
        {.....
};`

Additionaly, you can configure it in your nightwatch.json.
(Further reading http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#test-settings there. the "globals" in this test settings is the place where it should be then, per environment)

If defined in the nightwatch.json it will always win!

Also be careful: if you use retryAssertionTimeout globally, but define it in an assertion, it will also always win.